# How to convert "%d %H:%M:%S" formatted data without running into errors?

Tags: r

I have data strings which are like

```
31 05:58:57
```

which represents day 31, 5 am, 58 minutes, 57 seconds in UTC time.

I would like to convert to PST, which should be

```
31 10:58:57
```

which is day 30, 10 pm, 58 minutes, 57 seconds.

The day is just a day of the month. Is there a way to do this quickly in R?

I tried

```
as.POSIXct("31 10:58:57", format = "%d%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
```

but get an error.

Comment: what if you used %j instead of %d

Comment: @rawr That's day of the year, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is stupid, you should share your knowledge of the day and month with it using `paste0`. Then just read in as `'UTC'` and change attribute `'tzone'` to `'America/Los_Angeles'` in one swipe. Notice, that I used `'2022-07-'`, because I "knew" we needed summertime. For winter use something like `'2022-01-'`.

```
x <- '31 05:58:57'

`attr<-`(as.POSIXct(paste0('2022-07-', x), tz='UTC'), 'tzone', 'America/Los_Angeles')
# [1] "2022-07-30 22:58:57 PDT"
```

PS: `'PST'` refers to *pacific standard time*, i.e. winter, whereas `'PDT'` to *pacific daylight time*, i.e. summer.